# How to export your swagger documentation in fastify server to markdown？

Tags: node.js, swagger, markdown, swagger-ui, fastify

I use fastify-swagger in my fasitfy to create api documentation automatically.

It works great.

But i still need a markdown version.

How can i export swagger ui documentation to markdown files.

Comment: The swagger can be exported in json and XML, not markdown right now. I think other tools could apply the conversion

Comment: Check out Widdershins: https://github.com/Mermade/widdershins